# In case of concurrent VHosts, which one is serving?

Tags: php, apache, concurrency

I set up 2 virtual domain with Virtualmin, and while both of them are served by domain name, they both listen to the same ip/port.

Waiting for my domain names to be enabled, I tried to reach my ip on the 80 port listened by VHosts, and one of them is actually served. How does Apache decides which host to serve when there is 2 concurrents VHost on the same ip/port ? What are the rules about it ? First arrived, first served ?

It's pretty hard to find the correct keywords for this research on Google, as it is not really a problem, just a genuine question.

Comment: You can't have multiple virtual hosts with the same port and same name.

Comment: The example under https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html explicitly contains the comment `# This first-listed virtual host is also the default for *:80` There's also more explanation there.

Comment: If you want to test your both sites before your domain names are ready, you can edit your `hosts` file as admin and add a line such as `45.101.32.200 www.first-domain.com second-domain.org third.com`. You first put the IP address of your server then list the domains with spaces. Your computer only will then find your web server without doing a DNS request. The server will recieve the host name and switch to the corresponding virtual host. You'll need to restart your browser in order to take the new entry in your `hosts` file. Once the domains are ready, remove the line from `hosts`.